# How Clone BitBucket project from GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, bitbucket, github-actions

Is that possible to Clone the BitBucket project from GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do that by executing the `git clone` command in the `run` portion of a step in the workflow/composite action and use a secret to pass credentials for checking it out ex:

```
- name: checkout-bitbucket
  run: git clone ${{ BITBUCKET_REPO_URL }}
```

don't forget to set the BITBUCKET_REPO_URL secret on your repo, or add it as an `input`

Comment: Do you know how can I clone private BitBucket repo from GitHub Actions?

Comment: You can follow the step by step here: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/clone-a-git-repository/ using HTTPS or SSH, through command lines.